# Windows 10 on one SSD is corrupting windows 10 on the other SSD

Tags: windows-10, multi-boot

I have two SSDs. I installed windows 10 on one SSD and removed the SSD. When I installed windows 10 on the second SSD. When I insert both SSDs to computer and boot one of windows 10, it is corrupting the other SSD files and the other OS stucks on recovery mode. I ran CHKDSK and looks like it is corrupting recycle bin, bootmgr and other files. How to prevent one windows 10 from touching the other OS?

Comment: You have the same license for Windows 10 on both SSD and activated?  That would be your problem if so,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I disabled fast startup feature in both windows 10 and it solved the issue.